# ansible-playbook: error: unrecognized arguments: create-file.yml

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x, manageiq

When I try to run ansible playbook on target host (remote machine) I get the following error.

Any explanation to what this error means?

```
Identity added: /tmp/ansible-runner20211205-356-7iz5rz/artifacts/result/ssh_key_data (/tmp/ansible-runner20211205-356-7iz5rz/artifacts/result/ssh_key_data)
usage: ansible-playbook [-h] [--version] [-v] [-k]
                        [--private-key PRIVATE_KEY_FILE] [-u REMOTE_USER]
                        [-c CONNECTION] [-T TIMEOUT]
                        [--ssh-common-args SSH_COMMON_ARGS]
                        [--sftp-extra-args SFTP_EXTRA_ARGS]
                        [--scp-extra-args SCP_EXTRA_ARGS]
                        [--ssh-extra-args SSH_EXTRA_ARGS] [--force-handlers]
                        [--flush-cache] [-b] [--become-method BECOME_METHOD]
                        [--become-user BECOME_USER] [-K] [-t TAGS]
                        [--skip-tags SKIP_TAGS] [-C] [--syntax-check] [-D]
                        [-i INVENTORY] [--list-hosts] [-l SUBSET]
                        [-e EXTRA_VARS] [--vault-id VAULT_IDS]
                        [--ask-vault-pass | --vault-password-file VAULT_PASSWORD_FILES]
                        [-f FORKS] [-M MODULE_PATH] [--list-tasks]
                        [--list-tags] [--step] [--start-at-task START_AT_TASK]
                        playbook [playbook ...]
ansible-playbook: error: unrecognized arguments: create-file.yml
```

It seems like it has something to do with credentials. The `AWS - Ubuntu` is the private key for remote machine. If I don't use the credentials then the playbook executes locally on the manageIQ server and it works fine. But I want it to execute on the remote machine. I'm unable to figure out why ansible is throwing `ansible-playbook: error: unrecognized arguments: create-file.yml`. `create-file.yml` is the playbook name.

[image]

Comment: The missing part here is the exact command that is sent by your GUI. Once you get it the error should be obvious. I suspect one or more argument used by your GUI to build a command line are empty.